# Closing <li> tag in WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm using Three.js.
In my model it is possible to create a list of buttons by clicking on objects.
When I execute an li element it triggers the function but the result is shown after I click in the model again.

How can i get the focus back to the WebGl model without clicking, moving ...

```
<li class = 'test'>
    <button onclick='html3D();'>"+links[id].name+"</button>    
</li>
<li>
    <button  onclick='setShowRoom();'>Zum Wohnzimmer</button>
</li>
<li>
    <a href='"+links[id].target+"' target='blank' id ='zum_warenkorb'>Zum Warenkorb</a>
</li>
```

Edit: I figured out, I just can toggle the list between "open" and "close".

So the li - element vanished, but the problem of the focus back to my model is still alive.

Edit2: So it is a three.js problem, I think. If I set new values for the camera, by clicking on a button, the coordinations will be set but the camera is not moving. But it moves, when I click into the canvas. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2):

Did you alreadt [try the HTML DOM element `focus()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)?

```
document.getElementById("canvas").focus();
```

Comment: @user2982195 Maybe you can make a fiddle and show us that it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, a fiddle is not possible because of the interactive model

Comment: @user2982195 You don't have to reproduce the whole code, just the user case where focus is not on the canvas. I tried to reproduce your issue but don't get anything like you describe. Check **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLk218a1/8/)**. Focus is on the text input field (upper left corner) and still I can zoom / rotate without any problems.